# How to conect yandex or google maps to java+maven project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, yandex-mapkit

I need to conect dependency of maps to my project on java+spring+maven, but the build can't be succseed cause of android packages, maven don't see this dependency on his repo. What should i do to solve it?

I surffed all of the net, but i didn't find any good asks, all of the tips were posted earlier then 2020

Examples of errors and dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yandex.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapkit</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Unresolved dependency: 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:jar:3.5.0'
Unresolved dependency: 'com.android.support:support-v4:jar:27.0.0'
Unresolved dependency: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:jar:11.6.2'
Unresolved dependency: 'com.android.support:support-compat:jar:27.0.0'

Comment: Please do not make posts that have images, it is considered a bad practice on stackoverflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557